# Prove if $x_n \in C$ converges to $\bar{x} \in C$, then $C$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $C \subset X$ (where $X$ is a metric space) is closed iff $x_n \in C$ converges to $\bar{x} \in C$.

The first direction I have proved. For the converse, my attempted proof is:

"Suppose $C$ is open. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta (x) \subset C.$

Now take the sequence $x_n \in C\backslash B_\delta (x).$ Then by convergence, there exists an N such that for all $n > N$, $x^n \in B_\delta (\bar{x})$. This contradicts the construction of the sequence $x_n$. Hence $C$ must be closed."

Does this attempted proof make sense?

Comment: If a set is not open it does not follow that it is closed.

Comment: Please give your definitions of open/closed.

Comment: In metric spaces, if a set is not open this does not necessarily mean it is closed. Think about a subset of $\Bbb R$ of the type $[a,b)$

Comment: Moreover the correct statement should be "C is closed iff for every convergent sequence $x_n$ s.t. $x_n \in C \forall n$" the limit of the sequence is an element of $C$".

Answer (score 1):

Showing that $C$ is closed is  equivalent to showing that its complement $C^{c}$ is open. Suppose this is not true. Then there exists $x \in C^{c}$ such that $B(x,r)$ is not contained in $C^{c}$ for any $r>0$. For any $n$ there must be a point $x_n \in B(x,\frac  1n)$ which is not in $C^{c}$. This means $x_n \in C$ and $d(x_n,x) <\frac 1 n$. Thus $(x_n) \subseteq C$ and $x_n \to x$ but $x \notin C$ , This contradiction finishes the proof.